# Synchronizing a collection of shared resources in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a static collection of shared resources (text processor classes) in my C# application which respond to keywords. Each processor is stateful, and so does not work in a multithreaded context. I am looking for a good way to organize these so that I can make thread-safe access to them.

For instance, I could embed a sync object in each processor

```
public abstract class TextProcessor
{
    protected internal readonly object sync = new object();

    public abstract void Run( string text );
}

public class DocumentProcessor
{
    private static Dictionary<string,TextProcessor> s_procMap = ...;

    public void Run( string [] words1, string[] words2 )
    {
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem( Process, words1 );
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem( Process, words2 );
    }

    private void Process( object arg )
    {
        foreach( var word in words )
        {
            var proc = s_processor[word];
            lock( proc.sync )
            {
                proc.Run( word );
            }
        }
    }
```

Assuming that I can't rewrite my processors to be stateless (which is an option but would be a last resort due to the volume of refactoring), is there a better way to express this?

Comment: Is `TextProcessor` a super class to all processors?

Comment: Not sure why do you need mutlithreading here? Seems like all the syncronization issues might kill all of the performance benefits and signifficantly increase complexity of the code.

Comment: @SergeyRybalkin the text processing is causing longer than desired startup times so I am keen to investigate scenarios to mitigate that. Profiling has shown my input parsing to be a bottleneck so here I am trying to streamline it.

Comment: @AhmedKRAIEM yes, it's the base class for a moderately large hierarchy of processors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really don't want to change the processor... then I would make a wrapper.

```
public class ProcWrapper
{
  private TextProcessor _proc;
  private ActionBlock<string> _actBlock;

  public ProcWrapper(TextProcessor proc)
  {
    _proc = proc;

    _actBlock = new ActionBlock<string[]>(word=>
    {
      _proc.Run(word);
    });
  }

  public void AddWord(string words)
  {
    _actBlock.Post(word);
  }

  public void WaitForCompletion()
  {
    _actBlock.Completion.Wait();
  }
}
```

And use it similar to how you had it before:

```
Dictionary<string,ProcWrapper> s_procMap = ...;

void Run( string [] words )
{
  // NOTE: This assumes the same thread will access s_procMap.
  foreach(var word in words)
    s_procMap[word].AddWord(word);
}
```

I think this is close to what you're looking for.

Take a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228603.aspx for more info on `DataFlow` with `TPL` and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194684.aspx for info specific to `ActionBlock<T>`.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with the current approach is that a single busy `TextProcessor` can halt processing of the remaining words. If you instead gave each `TextProcessor` a (thread-safe) queue of words then you could enqueue work without blocking and have the `TextProcessor` dequeue and process the words in order.

Look at `ActionBlock` of the [TPL Dataflow library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228603.aspx). It handles the queueing, starting of a processing `Task` and the eventual shutdown of that `Task` in case no more work is left.

Note, that when no work is queued, no thread is blocked. This is an important scalability property.